# Confirmation dialog box for asp.net mvc button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Confirmation dialog box is not showing in my button click event. 
How can i show a message on button click ? The code is not working as expected.

Is there anything that i have missed in the code

Here i am including my code

cshtml

```
@model AjaxTest.Models.ProductModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ProductAjax";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>




<h2>ProductAjax</h2>
<div id="Productresult"></div>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Product</legend>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ProductAjax", "Product", new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Are you sure?",UpdateTargetId = "Productresult" }))
    {

        <div class="formRowContainer">
            <div class="labelContainer">Name</div>
            <div class="valueContainer">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessage("Name")
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearStyle"></div>
        <div class="formRowContainer">
            <div class="labelContainer">Description</div>
            <div class="valueContainer">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearStyle"></div>
        <div class="formRowContainer">
            <div class="labelContainer">Manufacturer</div>
            <div class="valueContainer">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Manufacturer)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearStyle"></div>
        <div class="formRowContainer">
            <div class="labelContainer">Price</div>
            <div class="valueContainer">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BasePrice)
                @Html.ValidationMessage("BasePrice")
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearStyle"></div>
        <div class="formRowContainer">
            <div class="labelContainer">Category</div>
            <div class="valueContainer">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, Model.Category, "--Select--")
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearStyle"></div>
        <div class="buttonContainer">
            <button>Add Product</button>
        </div>
    }
</fieldset>
```

===========

## Controller:

```
 public ActionResult ProductAjax()
    {
        ProductModel model = new ProductModel();
        return View(model);
    }
     [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ProductAjax(ProductModel model)
        {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("Product Name :" + model.Name + "</br/>");
            sb.Append("Description :" + model.Description + "</br/>");
            sb.Append("Manufacturer :" + model.Manufacturer + "</br/>");
            sb.Append("Price :" + model.BasePrice + "</br/>");
            sb.Append("Category :" + model.Category[model.CategoryId-1].Text);
            return Content(sb.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

## _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you added `jquery-unrobustive ajax js`?

Comment: Yes, i added. But not working and getting an error message "Unhandled exception at line 19, column 2 in http://localhost:25095/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined"

Comment: your jquery is not loading, please check your url? Put your jquery.js at the top from rest of jquery versions.

Comment: Where you are loading - `Jquery` and `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min`?

Comment: are you loading jquery.validate.min.js before jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js....  jquery.validate.min.js is also required before jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js... @ramiramilu

Comment: @jitendrajoshi not exactly, `jquery validate` is used for client side validation. for ajax to work, he needs to refer `jquery` and `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min` files, which I dont see getting loaded in his code.

Comment: Hi, I edited with all my scipts reference. When using all these, i am getting an error saying "Unhandled exception at line 19, column 2 in localhost:25095/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined"

Comment: you can remove jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js ... will not create any effect.. other same code is working fine in my system... i think ... we need to think something different.. @Sarat

Comment: You are not loading primary `JQuery` file.

Comment: You need to have something like this - `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` loaded before all validate and ajax js scripts.

Comment: Yes,... Please also note that jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js is not compatible with any jquery version higher than 1.8.3. jquery 1.8.3 is the latest version that is compatible with jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js.. @Sarat

Comment: @jitendrajoshi thats wrong, you can use higher versions of jquery as well.

Comment: @jitendrajoshi i tried your suggestion. But it is not working

Comment: @ramiramilu... I tried yours as well.. Still it is not working

Comment: This is my latest script. Do I need to add any jquer/Ajax refernce to the solution?

Comment: @Sarat, is javascript is enabled in your browser. and what browser are you using..(name & version) please...

Comment: @Sarat, do you have this `jquery-1.9.1.min.js` file in your `scripts` folder?

Comment: @ramiramilu.. no jquery-1.9.1.min.js is not there in the list

Comment: @Sarat Then which version you have in the `scripts` folder. You have use the version which is available to you in your project solution.

Comment: @ramiramilu i have jquery-1.10.2.min.js in my script folder. And i included in my cshtml.. But no change

Comment: @Sarat, what is the error? where you are getting it?

Comment: Now, no error is there. But the confirmation message is not displaying. Javascript and pop up are enabled in IE.

Comment: @jitendrajoshi I am using IE 11

Comment: @jitendrajoshi .. Please can you post the code you are using which works fine.. And do i need to add any configuration changes?

Comment: @Sarat, did you have this - `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />` in your web.config?

Comment: @ramiramilu.. Yes, I have

Comment: Can you post your `_Layout.cshtml`?

Comment: @ramiramilu.. Yes i added..

Comment: @Sarat, can you comment out `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` this line in layout and give it a try. Because you are adding these scripts manually at view.

Comment: @ramiramilu... Tried, But still the same. When click the button, it is not prompting confirmation dialog box..\

Comment: Only confirmation is not coming? or the ajax call is not working? I mean even though confirm popup never showed up, the ajax call might be happening, did you put a breakpoint on post action and see if it is hitting?

Comment: Yes, post action is happening. But Confirmation is not coming. I want to display the confirmation before post action

Comment: Is it happening only in IE, what about chrome and firefox?

Comment: Yes, Post action hitting in both IE and Chrome. Didn't try firefox as it is not installed in my machine. Can you please tell why this confirmation dialog is not coming?

Comment: So in chrome also you are not getting confirm popup?

Comment: Yes, Confirmation is not coming in chrome as well as IE